# Target method for UIButton not called when button is subview of UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uibutton

I have a UIButton in UICollectionViewCell. UIButton has a target on touch up inside event. How do I make sure that this target method is called on tap of button and not the UICollectionView delegate method?

Comment: The @IBAction associated with the UIButton will be called. What behavior are you seeing?

Comment: I have programatically created the button. UICollectionView delegate of didSelectItemAtIndexPath is called instead of UIButton Target.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: your buttons userInteraction is enable? 
and check in view bebug is your button is above the collectionView cell?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code.

On viewDidLoad method, here CollectionCell is the custom cell I've created.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.register(CollectionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell")
}
```

CollectionView DataSource method,

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionCell

        let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        btn.tag = indexPath.row
        btn.setTitle("Tap Me", for: .normal)
        btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        btn.addTarget(self, action:#selector(btnTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.addSubview(btn)

        return cell
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 30
    }
}
```

and UICollectionView Delegate method,

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Did Select")
    }
}
```

Your button click method will be like this,

```
@objc func btnTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    print("Button tapped at index ", sender.tag)
}
```

It works fine for me. Please do necessary changes as per your requirement.

Let me know in case of any queries so I can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily find which event is called. If you click on `collectionView cell` then `collectView delegate` method called which is

**SWIFT**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("collection did select")
    }
```

And if you click on button of cell

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionCell

        cell.YOUR_BUTTON.tag = indexPath.item
        cell.YOUR_BUTTON.addTarget(self, action:#selector(btnClick(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell
    }

@objc func btnClick(sender: UIButton) {
    print(sender.tag)
}
```

**OBJECTIVE C**

```
 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.YOUR_BUTTON.tag = indexPath.item
    [cell.YOUR_BUTTON addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
    NSLog(@"collection did select");
}

-(void)btnClick(sender: UIButton) {
    NSLog(@"button click index %d",sender.tag)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for UICollection view i am using this code modify it according to your requirement

```
 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    static NSString *identifier = @"cellIdentifier";
    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    for (UIView * subView  in cell.contentView.subviews)
    {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            yourButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:103];
        }
    }

    [yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(AddFriends:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [yourButton setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    return cell;
 }


 -(void)AddFriends:(id)sender
 {
    [self showLoadingView];
    UIButton *btnTapped = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSString* detailsId = btnTapped.accessibilityIdentifier;
    NSLog(@"str ID : %@",detailsId);
    .
    .
    .
    .
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers above are correct and will give you your desired result, but i suggest you to make your own protocol for the cell class and implement the delegate method to get the result rather than working with tag and all.

I have answered it in another post as well. Please check the link.. and do stop assigning tag and using it to indentify your button and implement the button click

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48882197/9130596