# UITableViewCell Image change after operation is finished

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, avaudioplayer

I have a problem about changing image when audio is finished. How i change the image of cell ? Please help me. I printed "Done" with 'audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying' but i dont know how to control the cell image or etc.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if messageList[indexPath.row].fileAudioUid != nil {
        let url = "..."
        startDownload(audioUrl: url)
    }
}


var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!
func startDownload(audioUrl:String) -> Void {
    let fileUrl = self.getSaveFileUrl(fileName: audioUrl)
    let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
        return (fileUrl, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
    }

    Alamofire.download(audioUrl, to:destination)
        .downloadProgress { (progress) in
            print(progress)
        }
        .responseData { (data) in
            let url1 = data.destinationURL?.absoluteURL
            print(url1!)
            do {
                self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url1!)
                self.audioPlayer.delegate = self
                self.audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                self.audioPlayer.play()
            }catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
    }
}

func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
    if flag {
        print("Done")
    } else {
        // did not finish successfully
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not add your solution to your question. Instead, you can answer the question by clicking the "Answer Question" button below or by selecting another person's question as your answer. This will automatically mark the question "solved".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retain a reference to the cell

```
let cellRef: IndexPath?

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if messageList[indexPath.row].fileAudioUid != nil {
        let url = "..."
        startDownload(audioUrl: url)
        cellRef = indexPath

    }
}
```

Then

```
func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
    if flag {
        print("Done")
       let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at:cellRef)
       cell.image = "myImage.png"
    } else {
        // did not finish successfully
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If AudioCell is the label then maybe you have to go to iterate through all the cell and look for that label.

Comment: i solved with "let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! MessageAudioCell" . Thank you for reply

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to update `UItableViewCell` image.

Keep track of `IndexPath`.

```
var cellRef: IndexPath?
    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
            if flag {
                print("Done")
                guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: cellRef) as? YourTableViewCell else {
                    return
                }
                cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "YourImageName")
                self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                self.tableView.endUpdates()
            } else {
                // did not finish successfully
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

i see that you have a single method for your audio download, what if you click multiple cells one after another, all the cell are calling same method in your view controller to download the audio. you need to have a reference for the cell you are downloading the audio for. so i say implement the audio download method inside cell class, and after download success, update your cell's datasource, that the audio has been downloaded, as you did

```
if messageList[indexPath.row].fileAudioUid != nil {
    let url = "..."
    startDownload(audioUrl: url)
    cellRef = indexPath

}
```

its good that you have a single instance of audio player. you need to implement your own protocol method for cell, which when completes its download calls the delegate method to play the audio for cell

sample example of protocol implementation is available at :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48882197/9130596

this is for collectionview cell but its the same thing, you can do it for tableview cell as well,

now you can play the audio in cell.. and also maintain a reference of cell whose audio is being played as answered by @stevenpcurtis, and upon successfull audio play completion, get the cell for that indexpath and update the imageview's image accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using cell in AVAudioPlayer delegate, use a bool state to know that audio is finished or not.
Or use isPlaying property of AVAudioPlayer to know it is playing or not and you can change image in "CellForRow" method accordingly.